# Python Debugging in VsCode : Module not found error

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, debugging

I have been trying to run the debugger for my python file. However, I get module not found for the import statements which are importing modules outside the directory of my python file which I am trying to debug. I looked everywhere on StackOverflow and found a few answers but it didn't work.  My `launch.json`:

```
{
    "name": "Python: Current File (Integrated Terminal)",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "launch",
    "console": "integratedTerminal",
    "python": "/Users/{NAME}/projects/toolchain/engine/engine/roles/process/files/myenv/bin/python3",
    "program": "${file}",
    "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
    "env": {"PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}${pathSeparator}${env:PYTHONPATH}"},
    "stopOnEntry": true,
    "justMyCode": false
}
```

and `settings.json`:

```
...
    "python.analysis.extraPaths": [
        "./engine/engine/scripts",
        "./engine/engine/roles/services/tcpdump/files"
    ],
    "terminal.integrated.env.osx": {
        "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}:${env:PYTHONPATH}"
      },
```

This is the import statement and the error:

```
import process_variables as pv
```

```
Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError
No module named 'process_variables'
```

The location of my python script is : `../projects/engine/engine/scripts`
and location of the script I am trying to import is : `../projects/engine/engine/roles/services/tcpdump/files`

Comment: investigate the content of `PYTHONPATH` **INSIDE** the script, `${pathSeparator}` is for separating components in file paths

Comment: you add `${workspaceFolder}` to `PYTHONPATH` but how does that all relate to file path `../projects/engine/engine/roles/services/tcpdump/files`, can you find file the file given the dirs in `PYTHONPATH` and the `import` statement

Comment: Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

**[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)**

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code above the import statement：

```py
import sys
sys.path.append("./engine/engine/roles/services/tcpdump/files")
```

[image]

Or add the following configuration in ***launch.json***：

```json
            "env": {
                "PYTHONPATH":"./engine/engine/roles/services/tcpdump/files"
            }
```

Comment: I have both. Still doesn't work.

`sys.path.append("../../../scripts")
import process_variables as pv`

    `"env": {
        "PYTHONPATH":"./engine/engine/roles/services/tcpdump/files"
    }`

Comment: Are you the same as the file structure in my answer? If different, the path in the code needs to be modified. Please refer to the path in my answer instead of `../../../`.

Comment: The code works fine if i run it normally (didn't make any change there). Just the debug mode is failing. so there should be no issue with the above path.

Comment: Okay, give your complete reproducible example, along with a step-by-step explanation of what you did and where you encountered the error.